# How to add 'quick steps' style control to Outlook 2010 Ribbon?

Tags: c#, user-interface, outlook, outlook-addin, ribbon

As part of my Outlook Addin I would like to add a control to the Ribbon which has the same format as the 'Home\Quick Steps' and 'View\Arrangement' controls. Does anyone know if these can be created by Addins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are variation of the in-ribbon gallery, you are currently not able to build ones yourself, you can only do drop down galleries. I believe that it has been request by alot of devs.

Marcus